# "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to plot some data in ggplot. I've been looking through several other answers and I can't quite figure out why other answers don't work for my situation.

I am trying to plot a data frame which is a combination of 4 data frames using rbind. They all have the same number of columns and the same formatting.

let's say for example it looks like this

```
Name   Day  Daily_Poten_V  I_uAmp  
1   Andy    1       .21           2
2   Andy    5       .45           3
3   Red     1       .74           2
4   Red     5       .53           5
5   Lola    1       .32           6
6   Lola    6       .21           2
7   Kyla    1       .23           1
8   Kyla    3       .45           2
```

I can make a plot using ggplot of x=Day and y = Daily_Poten_V no problem but when I try and plot x=Day and y = 'Daily I_uAmp' I get the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

These are the actual lines of code that I run:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
```

Theres a lot of other coding there that gives me the final tables called in the next section.

```
 y_zero <- 0
    all_reactors <-rbind(Andy_table, Red_table, Lola_table, Kyla_table)
    p_voltage <- ggplot(all_reactors, 
      aes(x=Day, y='Daily I_uAmp', colour=Reactor)) + 
      theme_bw() + 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 20), limits = c(0, 500)) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor =  element_blank(), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5), axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"), legend.position="bottom") + 
      ylab("Current (uA)") + 
      xlab("Day") + 
      geom_point()

p_anpot <- ggplot(all_reactors, 
  aes(x=Day, y=Daily_Poten_V, colour=Reactor)) + 
  ylab("Anode Potential (V)") + 
  xlab("Day") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5), axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"), legend.position="bottom") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5, 0.5, by = 0.1), limits = c(-.5, 0.5))+ 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=y_zero)) +
  geom_point()
```

with p_anpot showing me the graph I want and p_voltage giving an error. The error does show up when I try to give the y scale limits. If I run the line of code without scale_y_continous then I get a plot but there are no y axis points and just one straight line across 0. I assume that I have some large points somewhere and need to zoom in but when I do it doesn't seem to work.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Use `aes_string` and quote all variable names, e.g. `aes_string(x = 'Day', y = 'Daily I_uAmp', color = 'Reactor')`.

Comment: With `aes(..., y = "Daily I_uAm")` you are telling `ggplot` that all your y-values are the character string:  "Daily I_uAm". This becomes a problem when you try to fit a continuous scale to the y-values with `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: Is "Daily I_uAmp" a variable? We can help you best if you can post a `dput(all_reactors)` for us to work with

Comment: In your first table doesn't have a column  "Daily I_uAmp" just "I_uAmp".

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Having the space in my column name was causing more headaches so I ended up changing the column name to Daily_I_uAmp and ggplot worked perfectly for the p_voltage plot.